# jquery each() item.[value]

Tags: jquery, uitableview, key-value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustomerIDbtn").click(function () {
        DoaTable(myTB, "../Customer/Index", "客户管理", "CustomerID", "Name", "#CustomerIDV", "#CustomerID")
    });
    $("#btnWBTypeID").click(function () {
        DoaTable(myTB, "../WBType/Index", "提单类型", "WBTypeID", "Name", "#WBTypeIDV", "#WBTypeID");
    });
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        DoaTable(myTB, "../Customer/GetCustomer");
    });
    function DoaTable(TableID, url,TLName,TID,TName,LV,LID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var tbBody = "<tr><th>" + TLName + "</th></tr>";
                var a =  TID;
               $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                   tbBody += "<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"  class=\"aaf\" data-id=" + item.'TID' + " data-name=" + item.Name + ">" + item.Name + "</a></tr>";
                });
                $(TableID).empty();
                $(TableID).append(tbBody);
                $('.aaf').click(function () {
                    var usersid = $(this).data("id");
                    var userName = $(this).data("name");
                    $(LV).val(usersid);
                    $(LID).text(userName);
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

why TName is no equrt item.CustomerID  what it`s the problem?
thank u
how can just take mistake out?

why item.TName is no equrt item.CustomerID ? what it`s the problem?
thank u
how can just take mistake out?

Comment: What error do you get. I see some syntax issues with the code. First, item.'TID' is invalid, it should be item.TID. Also, you need to close '<td>' in your each loop. Why do you need 'var a =  TID;
' ?

Comment: Think he wants to use item[TID] (i.e. use the value of TID as the name of the property to address). And the var a = TID; seems test/debug code.

Comment: Oh.. and "myTB" is undeclared

Comment: Thanks Smit i want use the value of TID but it`s couldn`t work..

Comment: Li Ming - Could you post your controller code to have a better understanding of what your trying to do ?

Comment: it`s just a json         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(db.Customers.ToList());
            }
            else
            return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }